# How to determine background size for leaderboard?

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I have limited opinion about front end development. When it comes to determine background size, I always pick wrong sizes.
I could not find any documentation that shows how to select image/background sizes properly.

For example:
https://www.newlook.com/uk
I would like to use .gif image as a background in big leaderboard.
id = singleBanner
What the dimensions should i use in this case ? and How can i determine this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand everything but maybe you should use % on your width or else parameter to specify the dimension instead of set the exact dimension in pixel?

Otherwise, using framework like bootstrap, fundation, material UI help us to do anything we want

**EDIT**: in the case to find the dimension of an image you want to use in your website, i advise you to use placeholder.com, which allow you to place everywhere you want a false image, and you can set the dimension of it in html like below :

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
```

or

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/521x425">
```

That pretty useful to test, you can set any pixel dimension and you will probably find the size you want

Check the website to find any command like for the extension .jpg, .gif, .png, or the color

Comment: I had one .gif 1200x700 for that size banner. Unfortunately, it doesn't fit well. I did not understand how to pick proper gif size for designer.

Comment: do you mean you don't know what gif dimmension you need for your leaderboard or you dont know what size to give to the image in your code ?

Comment: I am working with a designer  and working as a backend engineer previously. I have literally no idea about front end, that's why my question was not clear that much, sorry about that. @tintiGust, thanks for asking. I do not know what gif dimension i need for leaderboard. Also, it is my general question that is how to determine proper sizes for banner.  There is no dimension(width and height) in my code for that banner. It covers all page in mobile and desktop. I requested 1200x70 and tried to fit in that banner. But it didn't fit. ----->

Comment: When i check google developer console, it shows my screen resolution. In this case i don't know which size i need to give designer. I know that if i give wider sizes(1900x70), it will look small or if i give low resolution(1200x70), it will look bigger inside div and looks  low resolution. This is my HTML code. 
    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;

Comment: ah if i understand you want to get the size of your background leaderboard for your designer to make a gif to this dimmension. so that way you have a clean gif appears into the leaderboard ?

Comment: yes it is correct! any idea how to pick correct size ? :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention in my subject. It literally saved my day and it will give a clearer idea of how image choosing works. 
1-)According to this reverse engineering or testing tool(placeholder.com), If div/banner covers full screen, Do i need to choose length as higher as possible such as 1920 which is nowadays more common one ? 
2-)Of course, it needs to be a limit like not over than 2500, therefore it might cause a small text or image appearance, doesn't it?

Comment: 3-)Lastly, for the other div which have specific dimensions like 90x90. Is it better to ask for that size to designer or Is it better to ask a bit higher resolution like 150x150 to give better appearance on browsers ?

It would be perfect if you have an idea about these questions and then i will update my question to make it clear and you can update your answer.

Comment: reading your comment, i think the easiest way do manipulate different size to have a responsive app/website for a beginner in front end is to use a framework like bootstrap, (the one i advise you) because it is really well documented, and it is made for responsive and fast developpment

using bootstrap would allow you to have one common img like 1920x1080 and after set it up to smaller screen, bootstrap will size it by his own